# SQL Server - Setting multiple columns from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

Table 1

```
ID  Code1 Code2 Code3
10    1.1   1.2   1.3
```

Table 2

```
Code  Group  Category
1.1     a     cat1
1.2     b     cat1
1.3     c     cat2
1.4     d     cat3
```

Now I need to get the outputs in two different forms from these two tables tables

Output 1

```
ID   Group1  Group2  Group3
10     a       b       c
```

Output 2

```
ID   cat1   cat2   cat3
10     1     1      0
```

Here the cat1, cat2, cat3 columns are Boolean in nature since the table 1 did not have any code corresponding to cat3 so the value for this is 0.

I was thinking of doing this with case statements but there are about 1000 codes mapped to about 50 categories. Is their a way to do this? I am struggling to come up with a query for this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on Output 2.  Are you envisioning a query with N columns, and you have only listed 3 of them?  The abstract nature of your question makes it more difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I *strongly* suggest you look into an alternative. This will get messy very fast, as you're essentially treating rows as columns. It doesn't help much that `Table1` is already denormalized - though if it really only has 3 columns, it's not that big of a deal to normalize it again.:

```
CREATE VIEW v_Table1 AS
   SELECT Id, Code1 as Code FROM Table1
   UNION SELECT Id, Code2 as Code FROM Table1
   UNION SELECT Id, Code3 as Code FROM Table1
```

If we take you second query, it appears you want all possible combinations of `ID` and `Category`, and a boolean of whether that combination appears in `Table2` (using `Code` to get back to `ID` in `Table1`).

Since there doesn't appear to be a canonical list of `ID` and `Category`, we'll generate it:

```
CREATE VIEW v_AllCategories AS
   SELECT DISTINCT ID, Category FROM v_Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2
```

Getting the list of represented `ID` and `Category` is pretty straightforward:

```
CREATE VIEW v_ReportedCategories AS
   SELECT DISTINCT ID, Category FROM Table2 
   JOIN v_Table1 ON Table2.Code = v_Table1.Code
```

Put those together, and we can then get the bool to tell us which exists:

```
CREATE VIEW v_CategoryReports AS
    SELECT
       T1.ID, T1.Category, CASE WHEN T2.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Reported
    FROM v_AllCategories as T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN v_ReportedCategories as T2 ON
       T1.ID = T2.ID
       AND T1.Category = T2.Category
```

That gets you your answer in a normalized form:

```
ID  | Category | Reported
10  | cat1     | 1
10  | cat2     | 1
10  | cat3     | 0
```

From there, you'd need to do a `PIVOT` to get your `Category` values as columns:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    cat1,
    cat2,
    cat3
FROM v_CategoryReports
PIVOT (
    MAX([Reported]) FOR Category IN ([cat1], [cat2], [cat3])
) p
```

Since you mentioned over 50 'Categories', I'll assume they're not really 'cat1' - 'cat50'. In which case, you'll need to code gen the pivot operation.

[SqlFiddle with a self-contained example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9f0a/1/0)

Comment: Thanks. This is something that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

These answers assume that all 3 codes are available in table 2.  If not, then you should use OUTER joins instead of INNER.

Output 1 can be achieved like this:

```
select t1.ID,
       cd1.Group as Group1,
       cd2.Group as Group2,
       cd3.Group as Group3
from table1 t1
inner join table2 cd1
on t1.Code1 = cd1.Code
inner join table2 cd2
on t1.Code2 = cd2.Code
inner join table2 cd3
on t1.Code3 = cd3.Code
```

Output 2 is trickier.  Since you want a column for every row in Table2, you could write SQL that writes SQL.

Basically start with this base statement:

```
select t1.ID,
//THE BELOW WILL BE GENERATED ONCE PER ROW
Case when cd1.Category = '' OR 
          cd2.Category = '' OR
          cd3.Category = '' then convert(bit,1) else 0 end as '',
//END GENERATED CODE
from table1 t1
inner join table2 cd1
on t1.Code1 = cd1.Code
inner join table2 cd2
on t1.Code2 = cd2.Code
inner join table2 cd3
on t1.Code3 = cd3.Code
```

then you can generate the code in the middle like this:

```
select distinct 'Case when cd1.Category = '''+t2.Category+''' OR 
          cd2.Category = '''+t2.Category+''' OR
          cd3.Category = '''+t2.Category+''' then convert(bit,1) else 0 end as ['+t2.Category+'],'
from table2 t2
```

Paste those results into the original SQL statement (strip off the trailing comma) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In output 2 I want columns for all categories from table 2 and they are Boolean in nature representing 1 if there is a code corresponding to that category in table 1 for that particular ID, else 0. Eg: For ID 10, there is code corresponding to Cat1 and Cat2 so the value for both is 1 but there is no code for Cat3 so the value is 0.

Comment: Will your final solution have 50 columns, or really "N" because you will have a column for every distinct category in Table2?

Comment: Yes that's correct. There will be "N" columns for every distinct category.

Comment: Is my answer for Output 1 sufficient, or you will ALSO want N columns for that answer?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Pivot feature and build the query dynamically. Some what like below:

Query 1

```
Select * from 
(SELECT Id, Code, GroupCode
FROM Table2 join Table1 
 ON Table1.Code1 = Table2.Code 
 OR Table1.Code2 = Table2.Code 
 OR Table1.Code3 = Table2.Code 
) ps
PIVOT
(
Max (GroupCode)
FOR Code IN
( [1.1], [1.2], [1.3])
) AS Result
```

Query 2

```
Select * from 
(SELECT Id, GroupCode, Category
FROM Table2 join Table1 
 ON Table1.Code1 = Table2.Code 
 OR Table1.Code2 = Table2.Code 
 OR Table1.Code3 = Table2.Code 
) ps
PIVOT
(
Count (GroupCode)
FOR Category IN
( [cat1], [cat2], [cat3])
) AS Result
```

Answer (score -1):

The PIVOT and CROSS APPLY keywords within MSSQL would help you out. Though it's not exactly clear what you are trying to accomplish. CROSS APPLY for performing a join on a correlated subquery and displaying different output for each join, and PIVOT for doing a crosstab on your data.

For table 1 it might be easier if you mash it together into a more normalized style.

```
WITH cteTab1 (Id, Code) AS
(
SELECT Id, Code1 FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Code2 FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Code3 FROM Table1)
SELECT *
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN cteTab1 ON Table2.Code = cteTab1.Code
```

Comment: This does not answer the OPs question.  Where is Output1 and Output2 generated?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately your stuck with a bad design for Table1.  A better approach would have been to have 3 rows for ID 10.

But, given your current design, your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT ID, G1.Group Group1, G2.Group Group2, G3.Group Group3
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 G1 ON T1.Code1 = G1.Code
INNER JOIN Table2 G2 ON T1.Code2 = G2.Code
INNER JOIN Table2 G3 ON T1.Code3 = G3.Code
```

and

```
SELECT ID, G1.Category Cat1, G2.Category Cat2, G3.Category Cat3
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 G1 ON T1.Code1 = G1.Code
INNER JOIN Table2 G2 ON T1.Code2 = G2.Code
INNER JOIN Table2 G3 ON T1.Code3 = G3.Code
```

Comment: This is what I thought too, but the OP says that Output 2 is a boolean, NOT just the corresponding Category.  So...... I'm stumped.